# Print counter and string for first n elements from list of strings, with default value, when n > list index-1

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I'm currently playing around a bit with streams in Java 8 and by rewriting some code I came up with the following situation.

- I have a list of strings which has a dynamic size.
- I want to print out the first five strings of the list, or `-` as
  default for all remaining entries, if the list size is less than
  five.
- The printed message needs to include a counter of the current string.

So for example the following list:

```java
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("one", "two");
```

Should print out:

```
1: one
2: two
3: -
4: -
5: -
```

So far I came up with the following solution:

```java
// Iterating over the existing entries
int i = 1;
for (String string : strings) {
    System.out.println(i++ + ": " + string);
}

// Printing the default lines for all missing ones
IntStream.rangeClosed(i, 5).forEach(n -> System.out.println(n + ": -"));
```

Somehow it does not feel so clean as I'm using `System.out::println` the same way twice. Is there a cleaner way I could rewrite it, to have it all in one stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
IntStream.range(0, 5)
    .mapToObj(i -> String.format("%d: %s", i + 1, i < strings.size() ? strings.get(i) : "-"))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

It is the most elegant way to do it in just one 'loop'.

Your number of lines is always 5, regardless the length of the array. We also cannot stream over the elements only, because we also need the indexes. So `strings.stream()` won't work, as you already discovered.

We use `IntStream::range` instead, to provide use with five integers. Then we map each integer to the corresponding element, or `-` if it is out of bounds. At last we print the whole thing, using a method reference.

---

*I personally prefer to use the original indexes (0 to 4) instead of the 1-based ones (1 to 5). So `range(0, 5)` instead of `range(1, 6)` or `rangeClosed(1, 5)`.*

Comment: This one is beautiful though.

Comment: I was suprised to get an error for your solution: 

```Error:(23, 40) java: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
    java.lang.String cannot be converted to int```

Comment: @pdrersin That is because `map` expects an `int` to be returned. Of course, we are returning a `String` here, so it should be actually `mapToObj`. My bad. I updated the post.

Comment: Nice, thank you! Great explanation and easy use with the ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another simple way:

```
    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");
    Iterator<String> it = strings.iterator();

    for (int i=1; i<=5; i++){
        if (it.hasNext()) {
            String str = it.next();
            System.out.println(i + ": " + str);
        }else {
            System.out.println(i + ": -");
        }
    }
```

Good luck!

Comment: I literally just fixed it I did not see the dashes first